# What NFC reader is on my Android phone?

Tags: android, tags, nfc

I'm am currently developping an android app for NFC and I encountered strange behaviors on different android phones. For example a galaxy SII plus have its NFC crash when in contact with a raw NFC-A tag with proprietary commands. A galaxy SIII can't see Ndef message over the NFC-V protocol. And a galaxy nexus crashes when a tag has NFC-A and IsoDep technologies. Each device is running with android 4.1.0 or more and those behavior haven been observed with well-known applications such as Tag Info from research lab Hagenberg.

My question is,  are those problem related with a different NFC reader on the phones ( especially when the NFC crashes ) ? And is there a way to know which reader exactly I have on the different phones and what protocols it supports ?